# How to handle properly environment values starting with numbers in cmd.exe. (eg.3DSMAX_xxx)

Tags: cmd, command, environment

I tried to use an environment value in `cmd.exe` like below,

```
set MAX_PATH=%3DSMAX_2011x64_PATH%
echo %MAX_PATH%
set MAX_PATH
```

However it looks like the `%3DSMAX_2011x64_PATH%` always is treated as a `DSMAX_2011x64_PATH`.

I searched the answer for a day however I couldn't find it.

How can I handle it properly?

Answer (score 0):

The short answr is - don't use variablenames starting with a numeric. The reason is that `%n` with `n` numeric means "parameter `n` to the procedure".

If you absolutely **must** use such names, then

```
for /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%v in ('set') do if /i "%%v"=="3name" set "newthing=%%w"
```

Answer (score 0):

This will set the value:

```
set MAX_PATH=3DSMAX_2011x64_PATH
echo %MAX_PATH%
set MAX_PATH
```